# Combinatorics proof for identity $\binom{n+t-1}{t-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^t \binom{t}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

$$\binom{n+t-1}{t-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^t \binom{t}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

how do you prove this? I cant get creative enough to get a combinatorial proof. I have tried picking the problem apart but I can't seem to get a proof at the end

Comment: You need to do a better job typesetting this.  For starters, what is the indexing variable on the summation?  $n$?  $t$?  $k$?  What does it range between?  See [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting information and how to use $\LaTeX$ and MathJax on this site.

Comment: i'm not sure how to use latex but the indexing is k = 1 till t

Comment: As for a hint, a binomial coefficient of the form $\binom{a+b-1}{b-1}$ should make you immediately think of [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Meanwhile a summation like this should make you think of breaking into cases based on the size of the indexing variable.

Comment: @JMoravitz i'm kind of new to combinatronics, so i'm not what you mean

Comment: Do you mean *combinatorics*?

Comment: Please do not deface your question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

**Major Hint:**

How many ways can you distribute $n$ identical balls into $t$ distinct baskets where you allow some of the baskets to be empty?

> How many ways can you distribute $n$ identical balls into $t$ distinct baskets where exactly $k$ of the baskets are non-empty?

$~$

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)